# Issue on database connection on php page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

My SQL database connection page called init.php and I included that to other pages on localhost. My site is fine but when I upload my files on live server I see my site down.

My site files are in a folder on my computer and also on the live server.

Here's the issue:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/myshop/config.php';
require_once BASEURL.'helpers/helpers.php';
```

When I remove these lines my site will work
here is the page http://shooop23.byethost7.com/

Comment: One of those lines is probably causing an error, or overwriting a variable you use in one of the other scripts. Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: can i have chat with you dear @chris85 ? i am having a little problem or notices with my php codes

Comment: Add what you are getting to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

to

```
BASEURL
```

or you can use

```
../myshop/config.php or ../../myshop/config.php
```

depending where your file is located